# How do I use ucwords() to capitalize a letter after a slash?

Tags: php, string

I am trying to capitalize the T and P in "trailer/promo," but `ucwords()` will only capitalize the T. Is there a way to do this?

**Note:** I cannot just manipulate the string to convert each / to a space, and back to a slash because I'll be running it on strings like "Music Video" which should not have slashes in them.

Comment: How about http://codepad.org/zejq5qSA ? Or http://codepad.org/GGkKZrWs ?

Comment: That does work, but it creates another problem for me in that it add slashes to strings with spaces in them. Sorry, I should have been more specific. I added this cavet to the question.

Comment: There's a regex way to do this, taking into account probably more symbols like `-`, `--`, `(`, etc. I'm not so good at the regex though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ucword will not do that for unless you manage to space the words out and join them together again after ucwording each word.
Here is a simple example:

```
implode('/', array_map('ucwords',explode('/','trailer/promo')));
```

The code above simple makes an array from the string "trailer/promo" using the "/" as to separate words. And then run each word (using array_map() ) through ucwords().After each word is processed by ucwords, an array containing the processed values are joined together again using the same "/". All this is done is just one line.

Comment: I know that weird feeling.

Comment: Maybe I made the OP mad with the slash-space business. Tisk tisk.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Not verbatim. Thankful as I am for your help, your answer did not have quotes around `ucwords`, so it didn't work.

Comment: @nipponese - Also, it just needs to be a string; an unquoted group of alphanumeric characters, when not a defined constant, is (due to the infernal quirkiness of PHP) a string. See: http://codepad.org/xKQE10Sh The quotes are not required, but it's ok, if you prefer them. I prefer quoting array keys. There is a small gang of PHP coders who don't quote them, I am sure, just to bug *me*. `;)`

Comment: @JaredFarrish My php installation just throws up this warning: `Notice: Use of undefined constant ucwords - assumed 'ucwords'`. I'm using v5.3.15

Comment: @JaredFarrish Yeah, I don't know man. I just couldn't get it to echo the string and couldn't figure out why so I had to give the Accept to the answer that solved it.

Comment: @nipponese - It's alright. I'll get over my mock outrage and still somehow sleep at night, y'know? It's just funny how it goes. I figured someone with five times my rep would saunter in and whip out some amazing regex lexical parsing lambda monad, make my goofy literal approach look ham-fisted. But that didn't happen. That's probably more disappointing. Pedestrian, y'know? Don't worry about, I got enough rep.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the delimiter parameter of ucwords, since PHP 5.4.32 and 5.5.16, it is as simple as this:

```
ucwords($string, '/');
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods you could use. The less-reliable, hope-there's-no-whitespace option:

```
str_replace(' ', '/', ucwords(str_replace('/', ' ', "trailer/promo,")));
```

And then probably a more robust method:

```
implode('/', array_map(ucwords, explode('/', "trailer/promo,")));
```

http://codepad.org/N8FmWRz5

I'm sure I could probably think of some other. There's probably something like `filter_var()` out there, buried somewhere.

Comment: Is it? Phfft. I didn't think PHP deprecated anything, just found more junk to pile in.

Comment: Hey, it didn't record my edit time. It's like it never happened. Never. Happened.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it using delimiter in php 7.2.24

```
$word = "White/white pearl and silver";
$result = ucwords(ucwords($word)), "/");
```

Result string will be "White/White Pearl And Silver"

In Laravel 5.7

```
ucwords(Illuminate\Support\Str::title($word), "/");
```